# ubuntu clamav freshclam can't download main.cvd

Tags: clamav

I installed clamav on my ubuntu system and have been unable to get freshclam to download a database.

Manually it produces the following errors:

> sudo freshclam Sun Mar  1 14:32:32 2020 -> ClamAV update process
>   started at Sun Mar  1 14:32:32 2020 Sun Mar  1 14:32:32 2020 ->
>   daily.cvd database is up to date (version: 25738, sigs: 2202395,
>   f-level: 63, builder: raynman) Sun Mar  1 14:32:32 2020 -> main
>   database available for download (remote version: 59) Sun Mar  1
>   14:33:02 2020 -> ^Download failed (28) Sun Mar  1 14:33:02 2020 -> ^
>   Message: Timeout was reached Sun Mar  1 14:33:02 2020 -> ^getcvd:
>   Can't download main.cvd from https://database.clamav.net/main.cvd Sun
>   Mar  1 14:33:02 2020 -> Trying again in 5 secs...

When it runs automatically the log looks like this:

> rich@richdesktop:~$ sudo tail /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log Sun Mar  1
>   16:02:19 2020 -> Trying again in 5 secs... Sun Mar  1 16:02:24 2020 ->
>   main database available for download (remote version: 59) Sun Mar  1
>   16:02:54 2020 -> WARNING: Download failed (28) Sun Mar  1 16:02:54
>   2020 -> WARNING:  Message: Timeout was reached Sun Mar  1 16:02:54
>   2020 -> WARNING: getcvd: Can't download main.cvd from
>   https://database.clamav.net/main.cvd Sun Mar  1 16:02:54 2020 ->
>   Trying again in 5 secs... Sun Mar  1 16:02:59 2020 -> main database
>   available for download (remote version: 59) Sun Mar  1 16:03:29 2020
>   -> ERROR: Download failed (28) Sun Mar  1 16:03:29 2020 -> ERROR:  Message: Timeout was reached Sun Mar  1 16:03:29 2020 -> ERROR:
>   getcvd: Can't download main.cvd from
>   https://database.clamav.net/main.cvd Sun Mar  1 16:03:29 2020 ->
>   Giving up on https://database.clamav.net... Sun Mar  1 16:03:29 2020
>   -> main database available for download (remote version: 59)

I have searched thru the other questions on this site but found no help.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS Desktop with no virtualization.

Comment: Please advise the distro you installed (i.e., Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, et al.) and its version. Also please note if you are using virtualizaing, and if so, which virtual engine is used. Please click [edit] and add that information to your question; please do not use Add Comment.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem on Debian/KDE. I found [this bug report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/65225) which helped: simply edit freshclam.conf (`kate /etc/clamav/freshclam.conf`) and set ReceiveTimeout to something larger than 30.

For complete resolve there should be an error message that prompts you to do just that or a larger default value.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, every version from ClamAV 0.99 and down, including all patch versions, are unsupported, and are actively blocked from downloading new updates.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Ubuntu Desktop more recently (2023 Mantic).

My situation and solution was different, but as this is the first item that shows up for the error message, I'll add what I had to do here.

It seems that freshclam no longer plays nicely with SQUID proxies. So if you had a working freshclam + squid proxy solution, the fastest solution is to turn off proxying by editing
/etc/clamav/freshclam.conf

and commenting out any proxy related lines, eg:

```
# Proxy: http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:pppp/
#HTTPProxyServer aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
#HTTPProxyPort pppp
```

restart freshclam, and after it has downloaded the files, restart clamav:

```
sudo systemctl restart clamav-freshclam
```

Wait a while or until systemctl status tells you freshclam is done, and then:

```
sudo systemctl restart clamav-daemon.service
```